# Finding the difference between two fields using JavaScript in iText

Tags: javascript, adobe, itext

I would like to find difference between two fields using JavaScript in iText.

I am able to find the sum of them using below code:

```
  PdfStamper stamperResult = new PdfStamper(readersectionResult, new FileOutputStream(RESULT_NEW));

   stamperResult .addJavaScript("var nameField = this.getField(\"total\");"+ "nameField.setAction(\"Calculate\",'AFSimple_Calculate(\"SUM\",\"total1\",  \"total2\")')");
```

Is there any way to find the difference using 'AFSimple_Calculate' similar to what I did in the above code snippet?

Thanks for editing! I tried your suggestion but it does not seem to work for some reason.

```
stamperResult.addJavaScript(" var total1 = this.getField(\"value1\"); var total2 = this.getField      (\"value2\"); var subtr = this.getField(\"total\"); subtr.value = total1.value - total2.value;");
```

I separated newlines by spaces and added right escape characters.

I was also thinking of using a different logic for subtraction using AF methods : like this

```
stamperResult.addJavaScript("var nameField = this.getField(\"total\");"+ "nameField.setAction(\"Calculate\",'AFSimple_Calculate(\"SUM\",\"total1\",  \"-total2\")')");
```

In the above code I was trying to add -(negative value) to total 2 so that it will be subtracted from total1 though the AF method is still 'SUM'.

But that does not work.

The below simple code seem to work :

```
stamperResult.addJavaScript("var nameField = this.getField('total');" +
        "nameField.setAction('Calculate'," +
        "'subtract()');" +
        "" +"function subtract(){this.getField('total').value        
                            = (this.getField('total_1').value -this.getField('total_2').value); }");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your question because it contained many spelling errors. I didn't edit the code snippet because I don't know what the original code snippet is like. In any case: I think something went wrong during the copy/paste process, as I don't think your code snippet compiles in its current state.

In any case: as far as I know the AF-methods (the AF stands for Adobe Forms) may not be present in every viewer, and as far as I know Adobe didn't implement a way to subtract values from each other in the AFSimple_Calculate method.

For these two reasons, you may prefer regular JavaScript instead of using a pre-canned function that may or may not be pre-canned.

This regular JavaScript may look like this:

```
var total1 = this.getField("total1");
var total2 = this.getField("total2");
var subtr = this.getField("difference");
subtr.value = total1.value - total2.value;
```

I'm not sure if that answers your question. Maybe you just want:

```
var total1 = this.getField("total1");
var total2 = this.getField("total2");
var namefield = total1.value - total2.value;
```

You can put these lines inside a String using the right escape characters and replacing the newlines by spaces or newline characters.

Of course, you need to trigger this code somewhere. Below you'll find an example that puts the negative value of the content of a `value1` field into a `value2` field.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("js.pdf"));
        document.open();
        writer.addJavaScript("function makeNegative() { this.getField('value2').value = -(this.getField('value1').value); } ");
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(40, 740, 200, 756);
        TextField value = new TextField(writer, rect1, "value1");
        value.setBorderColor(GrayColor.GRAYBLACK);
        value.setBorderWidth(0.5f);
        PdfFormField field = value.getTextField();
        field.setAdditionalActions(PdfName.BL, PdfAction.javaScript("makeNegative();", writer));
        writer.addAnnotation(field);
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(40, 710, 200, 726);
        TextField neg = new TextField(writer, rect2, "value2");
        neg.setBorderColor(GrayColor.GRAYBLACK);
        neg.setBorderWidth(0.5f);
        writer.addAnnotation(neg.getTextField());
        document.close();
   }
```

Note that I used a Blur action. This means the method will be triggered as soon as you select another field after filling out the `value1` field.

Comment: Thanks Lowagie. I tried the way you suggested but it does not seem to work. I added my changes in my original question.

I too think AF-methods does not have subtraction.

Comment: I think you're close. The main difference is that you didn't set an action yet. So the syntax to subtract is correct, but it's never used.

Comment: Yes, I think I am missing it. Would you please tll/write it down how to set an action. I tried it different ways like setAction("MouseUp")...but I am not getting the right syntax.

Comment: From the top of my head, I'd say you need to define the /V action for the value1 and value2 fields. The moment the value of one of these fields changes, you need to trigger the (document-level!) method that calculates the total fields. Keep trying; it's the only way to learn ;-)

Comment: Ok. I will try. But can you please tell me how to negate a certain value using JS. For example if user enters 2 in field A, I want to show -2 in field B. If I get this I can get the subrtraction working I guess. And the resources available are so low on this topic, I am having a really tough time though I am learning stuff.

Comment: Yes, I can tell that. But no, I don't have the time. I'm preparing the next iText release and that demands my full attention.

Comment: Although it's against the rules of SO (we're not supposed to do people's homework in their place), I've written a small example to show how simple the solution to your problem is. Don't tell your teacher I wrote this for you!

Comment: Thanks Lowagie!! Actually I am not a student but I have some phobia related to JS. Anyway I was mainly looking for 'OnBlur' action. I did not know that tern used for that action and had tough time. Good luck for your iText next relaese.

Comment: And also I did not know that 'Calcuate' action can be used for all JS functions. I thought it can only be used for AF methods. My solution was simple....Please look at it if you have time..I am updating it.

Comment: Good example! I'm upvoting the question!